# Symfony infinite login loop

Tags: php, symfony, loops, authentication

I've been trying to tackle this problem I'm having with my Symfony App
which when ever I try to login I get redirected to my dashboard route as it should do but for some reason just before loading up the dashboard page it seems to hit my login authenticator trying to re-authenticate my user credentials but this time round there are no credentials to validate against as the eraseCredentials() method removes my the password from the authToken there for failing the second time round also this procedure keep running  in a loop hitting the authenticator and failing over and over and the only way I'm able to stop this behavior is by logging out.

This is my Login Authenticator

```
   <?php
namespace Cms\UserManagerBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class LoginAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $encoderFactory;

    public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory, EntityManager $entityManager, ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {

        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
        }


        $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);
        $passwordValid = $encoder->isPasswordValid(
            $user->getPassword(),
            $token->getCredentials(),
            $user->getSalt()
        );

        //$session = $this->container->get('session');
       // $passwordValid = true;
        //get default language
        //$session->language('language/id');

        if ($passwordValid) {



            $now = new \DateTime();
            $user->setLastlogin($now);
            $user->setLoggedInn($user->getLoggedInn()+1);
            $this->em->flush();
            $roles = $user->getRoles();

            return new UsernamePasswordToken(
                $user,
                $user->getPassword(),
                $providerKey,
                $user->getRoles()
            );


        }else{

            throw new AuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');

        }


    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken
            && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }
}
```

This is My Firewall setting

```
security:
    encoders:
        Cms\UserManagerBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

#    providers:
#        fos_userbundle:
#            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    providers:
        cms_users:
            id: cms_user_provider
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: UserManagerBundle:User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        cms:
            pattern: ^/admin/
            simple_form:
                authenticator: login_authenticator
                provider: cms_users
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: /admin/login
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /admin/dashboard
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin/login
            anonymous:    true
#        default:
#            pattern:    ^/
#            http_basic: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

My Login Controller

```
<?php

namespace Cms\UserManagerBundle\Controller;

use Cms\CoreBundle\Controller\CoreController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder;


class SecurityController extends CoreController
{

    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {

        /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
        $session = $request->getSession();

        if (class_exists('\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security')) {
            $authErrorKey = Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
            $lastUsernameKey = Security::LAST_USERNAME;
        }

        // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
        if ($request->attributes->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get($authErrorKey);
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $session->get($authErrorKey);
            $error = $error->getMessage();
            $session->remove($authErrorKey);
        } else {
            $error = null;
        }

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get($lastUsernameKey);

        if ($this->has('security.csrf.token_manager')) {
            $csrfToken = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('authenticate')->getValue();
        }

        return $this->renderLogin(array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
        ));
    }



    public function generateUrl($route, $parameters = array(), $referenceType = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH)
    {
        return $this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, $referenceType);
    }


    /**
     * Renders the login template with the given parameters. Overwrite this function in
     * an extended controller to provide additional data for the login template.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function renderLogin(array $data)
    {
        return $this->render('UserManagerBundle:Security:login.html.twig', $data);
    }


    public function checkAction()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
    }

    public function logoutAction()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.');
    }



}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Check path must also allow anonymous, otherwise how can the anonymous user authenticate if they must first be authenticated?

Add

```
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work, The funny thing is though when I comment out the access_control on my security.yml it logs me in but unauthenticated .

Comment: As far as I know the order is also important. Have you tried restricting all the routes first and then allowing anonimity on login and login check?

Answer (score 0):

Your eraseCredentials function must be empty.

Use it only if you use plainPassword.

---

If the problem persists, share with us your User class which implements UserInterface

---

**EDIT :**

I had not seen the date of the topic ... But I think my solution is the right one! :)

---

**EDIT BIS**

> ```
>  * Removes sensitive data from the user.
>  *
>  * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
>  * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
> ```

If you empty your password and not an unmapped plainPassword the loop is a normal reaction.